# A certain program only works if I do NOT use sudo when running

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, sudo

## Problem

I have a problem where if I run a program using sudo, I do not get the desired output, but if I run without sudo, it works correctly. I am using raspberry pi with c++, using [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) to access the GPIO. This program will eventually involve using PWM pins to set motor powers, for which wiringPi *requires* the use of sudo. So, I *need* to use sudo when running this program.

However, any program which uses the code I am using to get readings from encoders does not work if run with sudo, but everything else works fine with sudo. For example, if I run BETA/basicInchTest.cpp, My-own-encoder/workingInOneFile.cpp, or My-own-encoder/test.cpp using sudo, they will just print 0, but if I run without sudo, they will give the desired output, printing the position of the encoder. If I run any program besides those dealing with encoders (all of my LED programs), sudo makes no difference as to the output.

When I say "running with sudo", I mean using sudo ./a.out as opposed to ./a.out. I will use workingInOneFile.cpp as an example.

```
g++ workingInOneFile.cpp -lwiringPi 
./a.out
```

The above will correctly compile and run my code so that I receive the desired output.

```
g++ workingInOneFile.cpp -lwiringPi 
sudo ./a.out
```

The above will NOT compile and run my code so that I receive the desired output. The number 0 will be printed over and over regardless of how I turn the encoder.

## Possible Explanation

I think that this might have something to do with wiringPi's interrupt system which I use with the wiringPiISR() function because only encoder related programs have this issue, and that is their most unique aspect. All three of the files I mentioned deal with the encoders in slightly different ways in terms of class structure and the main similarity between them not found in other files which I can use sudo with is that they all use this interrupt. I have also already tried using -o to give a different name than a.out, with no effect on the output.

Is there any way I can use these encoders with sudo as I will eventually need to because the only way to control PWM pins is to use sudo.

## Code

workingInOneFile.cpp:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <iostream>

int position = 0;
unsigned char state = 0;

void update(void)
{
    unsigned char currentState = state & 3;
    if (digitalRead(7))
    {
        currentState |= 4;
    }
    if (digitalRead(0))
    {
        currentState |= 8;
    }

    state = currentState >> 2;

    if (currentState == 1 || currentState == 7 || currentState == 8 || currentState == 14)
    {
        position += 1;
    }
    else if (currentState == 2 || currentState == 4 || currentState == 11 || currentState == 13)
    {
        position -= 1;
    }
    else if (currentState == 3 || currentState == 12)
    {
        position += 2;
    }
    else if (currentState == 6 || currentState == 9)
    {
        position -= 2;
    }
}

void setup()
{
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode(7, INPUT);
    pinMode(0, INPUT);

    if (digitalRead(7))
    {
        state |= 1;
    }
    if (digitalRead(0))
    {
        state |= 2;
    }
    wiringPiISR(7, INT_EDGE_BOTH, &update);
    wiringPiISR(0, INT_EDGE_BOTH, &update);
}

int read()
{
    return position;
}

int main()
{
    setup();
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << read() << "\n";
    }
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "encoder.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Encoder enc(0, 7);
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << enc.read() << "\n";
    }
}
```

basicInchTest.cpp:

```
#include "encoderL.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

int EncoderL::position = 0;
unsigned char EncoderL::state = 0;

int main()
{
    EncoderL::begin();
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "Left: " << (EncoderL::read()/1440.0)*2.04*M_PI << "\n";
        
    }
}
```

Full github source: https://github.com/droiddoes9/Tennis-Ball-Robot/tree/master/General-Testing

Comment: This will most probably be an issue with environmental variables not existing with the root user.

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please [edit] your question to improve it, like for example telling us the expected and actual output in each case. And please tell us what efforts you've made in debugging your programs, like have you tried to use an actual debugger to step through the code statement by statement?

Comment: @RamanSailopal That would make sense because as seen [here](http://wiringpi.com/reference/priority-interrupts-and-threads/), for the case I am using (INT_EDGE_BOTH), the gpio utility program must be available, and I assume it is not available when using sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: update wiringPi to newest version :)